# How do you get other tag to increase intersection constraint?

Tags: sql, tags

I have an issue with a query which is running in 2 seconds because the subquery return 600 lines. I think I need to find a query without IN operator or a faster way to do my query.

Currently, I have this query:

```
SELECT tag.idtag, tag, COUNT(*) AS nombre
FROM tag, questtag
WHERE tag.idtag = questtag.idtag
  AND idquestion IN (
      SELECT question.idquestion
      FROM question, questtag
      WHERE question.idquestion = questtag.idquestion AND idtag IN (1)
      GROUP BY question.idquestion
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
  )
GROUP BY tag
ORDER BY nombre DESC, tag
LIMIT 0, 24
```

**I want to say in sql:**
"Get other tag related with Javascript tag (intersection constraint) like stackoverflow."

**I have 3 tables :** `question`, `questag` and `tag`.
`question` and `tag` are related by *questtag* table.

[image]

**Test values:**

```
QUESTION (idquestion, question) :
1, "Javascript and Jquery"
2, "HTML, CSS, Javascript"
....
```

```
QUESTTAG (#idquestion, #idtag) :

1, 1
1, 2
2, 3
2, 4
2, 1
....
```

```
QUESTTAG (#idtag, tag) :
1, Javascript
2, Jquery
3, HTML
4, CSS
....
```

**Expected:**

- With *Javascript*, I should match *Jquery*, *HTML* and *CSS*.
- With *Javascript, HTML*, I should match *CSS*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have better luck if you structured your query like this:

```
SELECT tag.idtag, tag, COUNT(*) AS nombre
FROM tag join questtag on tag.idtag = questtag.idtag
join (
      SELECT question.idquestion, COUNT(*) tags
      FROM question q2 join questtag qt2 on q2.idquestion = qt2.idquestion 
      AND idtag IN (1)
      GROUP BY question.idquestion
  )  temp on temp.idquestion = questtag.idquestion
WHERE tags = 1
GROUP BY tag.idtag, tag
ORDER BY nombre DESC, tag
LIMIT 0, 24
```

or you might not.  In any event, it's worth a shot.